# Ф. И. О. / ФИО / Ф.И.О

Tags: орфография, сокращения, аббревиатуры, условные-сокращения

Правда ли, что, несмотря на то что чаще пишут *ФИО*, нужно *Ф. И. О.* писать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Викисловарь**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9E), например, фиксирует так: ФИО.
Я пишу так же, без точек и пробелов (это быстрее в три раза).
Но если придётся сдавать экзамен или тест на тему сокращений, следует придерживаться закреплённых на данный момент написаний.

[**Ответы Грамоты.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A4.%20%D0%98.%20%D0%9E):

> Нормативные сокращения: *Ф. И. О.* и *ф. и. о.* См.: Русский орфографический словарь РАН / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – 4-е изд., испр. и доп. – М., 2012.

[**Список общепринятых сокращений**](https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#f) (Редакторское бюро «По правилам»):

> **Ф. И. О.** и **ф. и. о.** фамилия, имя, отчество